# Como posso converter DOC e DOCX para TXT com PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema onde os arquivos que o cliente vai me mandar são todos em arquivo `DOC` ou `DOCX`. Porém o mesmo quer que seja possível fazer o download desse documento em formato `TXT`.

Existe alguma maneira simples de converter `DOC` ou `DOCX` parar `TXT` através do PHP?

Comment: Já tentou o PHPWord?

Comment: Justamente, @rray, esqueci de especificar isso na pergunta. Sabe como se faz isso no `PHPWord`?

Comment: Acredito que estes dois links podem te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540886/extract-text-from-doc-and-docx

Comment: aqui tem outro exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php

Comment: Obrigado, galera. Estou começando a entender. Um arquivo `DOCX` é um arquivo zipado mascarado. Se você alterar a extensão do mesmo para `ZIP`, verá que o mesmo possui vários arquivos `XML` para formatação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

Abro o Documento WORD através da classe `IOFactory` da biblioteca `PHPWord`.

```
 $reader = PHPOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('Word2007');

 $phpword = $reader->load('arquivo.docx');
```

Salvo o arquivo como `HTML` num arquivo temporário:

```
$tempfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());

$phpword->save($tempfile, 'HTML');
```

Utilizo a classe `DomDocument` para achar somente a tag `body`

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

@$dom->load($tempfile); // Essa arroba é normal ;)

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Em seguida faço a esquematização para formatar o `HTML`. Também configuro ele para exibir corretamente no bloco de notas do `Windows`, trocando `"\n"` por `"\r\n"`.

```
 $txt = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", strip_tags($body));

 file_put_contents('arquivo.txt', $txt);
```